# send a predefined chart to the amchart editor

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

is it possible to send an already **amchart4** created chart to the **amchart editor** library?
I don't want to loose the data, colors, ... etc.

scenario:
1- create pie chart using amchart4 library.
2- fill and edit format of chart (to be the new default).
3- send created chart to editor if user wants to edit.

Comment: No, there isn't a way to serialize a chart object into a format you can paste into the editor.

Comment: that is a bummer but thank you